# Is there a way to change the playback speed of a screencast recorded with Camtasia for Mac?

Tags: macos, video, screencasts, playback, camtasia

Preferably within Camtasia for Mac but if I need to use another programme, I guess I will.

I recorded a 2.5hr coding session that I want to speed up to 2.5 minutes ideally... just for fun!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Mac, but in my Windows copy of Camtasia this is easy. In Camtasia Studio, after adding the clip to the timeline you right-click and select "Clip Speed". Allows you to set the speed as a percentage of original playback time. You have to produce the movie for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for playback, you can use Quicktime: Alt-clicking on fast forward or rewind will speed up or slow down playback speed (as will mouse-scrolling sideways). However, it will probably not go as fast as you want.

Comment: I meant more like increase the playback speed 10x or 100x or whatever and then export the movie that much sped up..

Answer (score -2):

1. Major innovation discovered today is that if you try to screen capture something at 2× in VLC – it won’t be able to process fast enough – but if you take the audio from the 2× version in VLC and then you change the clip speed of the video in Camtasia to 2× – you can layer the VLC 2× camrec audi on top of the video at 2× clip speed in Camtasia and get the result.
2. This allowed me to cut a 10 minute video to around 6 minutes for the JR ACAF.
3. I actually did everything with 1.5× audio and the trick was whenever the video was slow I split the audio/video track there and changed the clip speed to 140 – whenever the video was fast I split the audio/video track there and changed the clip speed to 155 – I ended up having to do this only 5-9 times since in other places the difference wasn’t noticeable.

Comment: You didn’t really answer the question,  did you?